How to Automatically Execute a Python Script on USB Insertion and Display Output in Linux?
In a Linux environment, if I have a Python script that displays specific text strings during execution and I want this script to run automatically when a USB drive is inserted, how should I proceed?
I have already tried using udev rules; the script executes, but nothing is displayed on the screen

"that displays specific text strings" – how? Where should the display show up?

The approach using udev rules is appropriate.
You need to ensure that your script interacts with the correct terminal (TTY). I assume you're using the CLI. Here’s how you can fix it:
import os

def main():
 message = "USB Drive Inserted!"
 # Write directly to the active terminal (usually /dev/tty1)
 with open("/dev/tty1", "w") as tty:
    tty.write(message + "\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()

As AKX mentioned, using a GUI alone won't suffice to display a message or information. A straightforward way to create a GUI notification is to:
import subprocess

def send_notification(title, message):
 subprocess.run(['notify-send', title, message])

send_notification("Hello!", "This is a notification from Python.")


If OP is using e.g. a graphical environment, this won't help at all.
